# Socket chat app Freezing when sending a message

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Hi I was following a tech with Tim tutorial about sockets and I am building a chat app and I am trying to create a dictionary with the names and the IP in it. but when I connect and type my name the client-side app freezes but I don't know why so can you see if you can help me this is the code.
Server-side code

```
import socket
import threading
import io

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "dis"
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
Names = {}


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg.split(':::')[0] == 'Name':
                name = msg.split(':::')[-1]
                Names[addr] = name
                print(Names.get(addr))
            elif msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
                print(f'[{addr}] Has disconnected')
                # Names.pop(addr)

            else:
                conn.send('message recieved'.encode(FORMAT))
                print(msg)

    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

And this is the client-side code

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "dis"
SERVER = '127.0.1.1'
print(SERVER)
Name = input('Enter your name: ')
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))
send('Name:::' + Name)
while True:
    msg = input('what message do you want to send type dis to disconnect: ')
    if msg != DISCONNECT_MESSAGE :
        send(msg)
    elif msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
        send(msg)
        break
    elif msg == None:
        print("please type a message and don't leave it a blank")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client code, under function `send(msg)` you are expecting response from server once the client sent a message, and you are using the same function for sending username as well.

In the server you have not coded to respond for username.

Hence your client is actually waiting for response from server, for the username it just sent. That's why it looks frozen.
Adding a response like `Hello username` in server will resolve this.

**Server**

```py
import socket
import threading
import io

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "dis"
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
Names = {}


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg.split(':::')[0] == 'Name':
                name = msg.split(':::')[-1]
                Names[addr] = name
                print(Names.get(addr))
                conn.send(f'Hello {name}'.encode(FORMAT))
            elif msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
                print(f'[{addr}] Has disconnected')
                # Names.pop(addr)

            else:
                conn.send('message recieved'.encode(FORMAT))
                print(msg)

    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```